# java jsp if statement

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jdbc, resultset

Following code gives me a big headache. Why does my `if` ignore `rs.next() == true`?

```
        System.out.println(rs.next());
        if (rs.next() == true) {
            System.out.println("1");
            session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
            //out.println("welcome " + userid);
            //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
            response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
        } else {
            System.out.println("2");
            out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
        }
```

Console:

```
#1 SELECT * FROM users where username = 'test' and password = 'test'

#2 true

#3 2
```

What am I doing here wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing here wrong?

You're calling `next()` twice. The first call returns `true`, but presumably the second returns `false` - which makes sense, if your query only returns a single result.

If you really want to print the value out for diagnostic purposes, save it in a local variable:

```
boolean nextResult = rs.next();
System.out.println(nextResult);
if (nextResult) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`ResultSet#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) advances the underlying cursor. Assuming the username is really unique, if found the first call to `next()` will return `true` and advance the cursor. When the second call is made, the cursor has already exhausted all its data, so it returns `false`. If you want to use this value, you need to keep it instead of calling `next()` multiple times. E.g.:

```
boolean hasNext = rs.next();
System.out.println(hasNext);
if (hasNext) {
    // Do stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

i did not get your problem exactly but first of all we should not write if statements like this

```
if (rs.next() == true) {
```

its wrong practice to check like this `if(boolVar == true)` it should be like this

```
if(boolVar){
```